# Chose a number between 1 and 9 to see what movie matches you more.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I received the following:

Chose a number in the set: $\{1,2,...,8,9\}$ then:

$-$ multiple by $3$

$-$ add $3$

$-$ multiple again by $3$

$-$ add the two digits together.

After that we check the film's list to see what movies matches more with us.

$1.$ The Matrix

$2.$ The Big Lebowski

$\cdots$

$8.$ The Godfather

$9.$ You Starring in a Obscene Act

$\cdots$

Question: How does this work?

My interpretation:

$3(3a+3) = 10b+c \tag{1}$

where $a,b,$ and $c$ are one digits numbers. $b+c = 9$ but how to prove it?

My attempt: $3(3a+3) = 10b+c \implies a = b-1 + (b+c)/9$

$(b+c)/9$ must be integer , so $b+c$ is divisible by $9$, then it's $9$ or $18$. If it's $18$ then
$a = b-1$, substituting in $(1) \implies c = -b$. I think this is not possible because of the negative sign, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hint. The left side is divisible by $9$, and $10= 9+1$.

Comment: It's clearly divisibly by 9 so this is an immediate consequence of **casting out nines** (see the linked dupe)

Answer (score 1):

The number $9a+9$ is a multiple of $9.$ So the sum of their digits is a multiple of $9.$ Since $18\le 9a+9\le 90$ the only possibility is that the sum of the digits is $9.$ Thus the movie is "You Starring in a Obscene Act".